# What characters are allowed in Shopify product handles?

Tags: shopify

Shopify's [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections/special-characters-in-handles) shows some of the characters that are allowed in product handles (the product identifier that is used in URLs).

> Since handles are used for your storefront navigation for products,
>   collections, blogs and pages, they must use alpha-numeric characters
>   (a-z, 0 to 9) without accents (such as umlauts, and other
>   diacriticals), nor characters such as @ or # etc., and no spaces.
>   Spaces will be converted to hyphens, other characters may be stripped
>   entirely or converted to an equivalent standard ASCII character.

But if I create a product in the web interface with the title 'a b-c_d.e' then the handle generated by Shopify is 'a-b-c_d-e'. It seems like underscores are allowed, but spaces and dots are converted to hyphens.

What is the full set of characters allowed in product handles?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a script to test if the Shopify API accepts each of the ASCII codes from 0 to 127 in a product handle. It tries to modify the handle of an existing product to xCxC where C is the ASCII character to test and x is literally the letter x. I did it this way to find out how each character is handled when surrounded by text and also when trailing at the end of the handle.

Here are the results:

**Allowed**:

- 0-9
- a-z
- A-Z   (will be converted to lowercase)
- _ (underscore)

**Allowed** when surrounded but **removed** when at the end of the string:

- - (hyphen)

**Converted to -** (hyphen) when surrounded but **removed** when at the end of the string

- space
- ! # $ % & * + , . / : ; < = > ? @ \ ^ ` { | } ~
- ASCII control codes 0 to 32

**Removed**

- " ' ( ) [ ]

---

See Wikipedia for details on each ASCII code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Double hyphens before and after `handleize` are converted to single hyphens as well; and non-Latin characters are converted to corresponding Latin characters.

Comment: This is no longer the case

Comment: Thanks! Starting from this, and adding extra guesswork, here is the code I got, in case it helps others:
`    option.toLowerCase()`
    .replace(/["'(){}[\]]/g, '')  // remove "nasty ones"
    .replace(/ /g, '-') // replace spaces by dashes
    .normalize('NFKD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '') // remove accents (more or less)
    .replace(/[^-_.a-z0-9]+/g, '_') // replace a series of NON -_.a-z0-9 by a single underscore
    .replace(/^[-_]+/, '') // remove heading dashes/underscores
    .replace(/[-_]+$/, ''); // remove tailing dashes/underscores

Comment: Darn, looks like I need a higher IQ to format a block of code in a comment! I reposted this code in a readable way as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated.

[Shopify allows many non-english characters inside URLs.](https://community.shopify.com/c/API-Announcements/Upcoming-changes-to-character-encoding-in-Shopify/td-p/438364)

Example

```
https://example.myshopify.com/collections/무료/products/이지부
```

is now a valid Shopify URL.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the Navigation feature used to create menus inside Shopify does not pass quotation symbols or inch symbol, i.e: " specifically when creating a custom URL link in a navigation menu.

The symbol is allowed when entered but it is removed before being passed to the liquid template files.

Unexpectedly, you can use this symbol to create a query URL, i.e:

```
.../tvs/lg?pf_opt_tv_size=28.5"
```

This is particularly annoying when creating a Navigation link to a custom query URL created by a search filter app, Shopify will internally remove these characters for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all the characters that are not affected by URL decode/encode functions.

Underscores (`_`) and Hypens (`-`) escape from this, also does the stop (`.`); but it's a URL schema parameter and hence gets converted to Shopify handle schema namely `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some code that may or may not be useful in your specific case:
(thanks @Liam for his helpful answer that lead to this)

```
option.toLowerCase()
  .replace(/["'(){}[\]]/g, '')  // remove "nasty ones"
  .replace(/ /g, '-') // replace spaces by dashes
  .normalize('NFKD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '') // remove accents (more or less)
  .replace(/[^-_.a-z0-9]+/g, '_') // replace a series of NON -_.a-z0-9 by a single underscore
  .replace(/^[-_]+/, '') // remove heading dashes/underscores
  .replace(/[-_]+$/, ''); // remove tailing dashes/underscores
```